# Idiom to say "with lowest impact"

Tags: expressions, idioms

We are changing a process in our company and I'd like to convey the message below to my clients.
"We are trying our best to change this process without affecting dependent processes" . Is there a phrase or idiom I can use here to say that we are doing this process change with lowest impact to  other processes?

Comment: I think you mean '_affecting_ dependent processes'. 'To affect' means to 'have influence on' or 'to change', 'to effect' means 'to cause to happen' or 'to carry out'. Don't worry, it's a common error.

Comment: Thanks i edited my question. But i am still looking for a good phrase or expression to convey my intent in the original question.

Comment: Minimal, minimize, limit. The “below message” strikes an off-note.

Comment: No magic phrase, but: You're trying to minimize/reduce/mitigate side effects / knock-on effects / unintended consequences

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any fancy language.

Borrowing from two of your sentences I suggest

*We are doing our best to make sure this change has the least possible impact on other processes.*

Answer (score 1):

- *We are looking for / believe we have come up with a magic bullet.*

> **magic bullet** [compound] noun
>
> something that cures or remedies without causing harmful side effects:
>
> - *So far there is no magic bullet for economic woes.*

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/magic--bullet)]